# UIRefreshControl Selector not calling objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

`UIRefreshControl` is not calling its selector. Here's the hierarchy of `UITableView`:

```
UINavigationController-UITabBarController-UIViewController-UITableView
```

Below is Code.

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[contestTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
[contestTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
[refreshControl layoutIfNeeded];
[refreshControl beginRefreshing];


-(void)handleRefresh:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"Pull To Refresh Method Called");
    [self getDataFromServer];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

refresh control is not calling handleRefresh function on pull down of UITableview.
Kindly help.

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try commenting below line form your code. Since you have already fired **beginRefreshing** the refresh operation in viewDidLoad and not returning the control to its default state using **endRefreshing()**, the selector **handleRefresh:** will not be fired.

```
[refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

**beginRefreshing()**: 
Tells the control that a refresh operation was started programmatically. And should be called only when  an external event source triggers a programmatic refresh of your scrolling view, for example you update tableview periodically using timer.

Comment: Tried by removing above line but now when tableview is pulled down refresh contol is not visible and no action is performing.

Comment: Might be with respect to your tableview content offset

Comment: Great,Thumbs up

Comment: you save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the refresh control first try the sample code

```
swift:
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        }


obj-c :

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [yourTableview addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: its swift and asking for objective c

Comment: you don't need to setContentOffset explicitly. and in which method you put your code to add refresh control